# Yii2 Codeception throws Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

Using Codeception to test a class that extends yii\base\Model.

```
class MyModel extends yii\base\Model
{
   public function __construct($some_obj, $config = [])
       $this->_obj = $some_obj;
       parent::_construct($config);
   ...
}
```

In the controller, the code is straight forward.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $some_obj = new SomeClass();
    $model = new MyModel($some_obj);
    ...
}
```

In production this code runs fine, but now I am adding some tests for this class using Codeception.  The only difference is that with the test I am using a stub for the injected object.

```
public function testValidation()
{
    $some_obj = $this->makeEmpty(SomeClass::class);
    $model = new MyModel($some_obj);
    ...
}
```

Problem is when executing new MyModel() in the test, the following message is thrown:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

The module that throws the message is ../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php.  The foreach loop is checking behaviors.  I have no behaviors defined in MyModel.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in behaviors of MyModel? My guess is you might be doing something with `$some_obj` in MyModel's constructor that makes that class call `behaviors()` method. But because it's empty stub the `behaviors()` call will return null instead of empty array causing that warning. You should check the backtrace to see where exactly the problem comes from.

Comment: @Michal Hynčica Yeah, you are absolutely correct.  makeEmpty creates a true stub without methods.  The init() of MyModel calls a method in $some_obj.  I have some refactoring to do.  Thanks for the clue!